# gradle tar.gz is not working/executed when inside doLast{}

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to create tar.gz file inside doLast{}.
Hence the code is not at all executed when it is inside doLast{} and no tar.gz file is getting created.
Bellow is my code :

```
task bundleCore(type:Tar,
         dependsOn[libCopy,nativeLibCopy,externalJarsCopy]){
doLast{
  from project.ext.get("tmpBundleDir")+"/"+coreSrcStr
  archiveName = coreSrcStr+".tar.gz"
  destinationDir = file(project.ext.get("src"))
  extension = 'tar.gz'
  compression = Compression.GZIP
  }
}
```

Please suggest any solution as I can not remove doLast{} part.

Answer (score 0):

> Please suggest any solution as I can not remove doLast{} part.

Well, in this case, it won't work. You are trying to configure a task **after** it is executed. How is this supposed to work?

Normally, you configure tasks during *configuration phase*. During *execution phase*, a task can be prepared via `doFirst`, then it gets executed (its actions) and after that, `doLast` is called (e.g. for logging or cleanup).

Answer (score 0):

Overcame this using ant to create tar.

```
task createTar{
    doLast{
        ant.tar(destfile: <tar file name>,
                basedir:<directory path to be zipped>, compression:"gzip" )
        }
    }
```

Refer [Tar](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tar.html) for help